# In R, how to match string that has irregular space

Tags: r

We are loading data from an excel file. Have the following issue going on:

```
> dput(names_col[54])
" Calvin Ridley SUS"
> dput(substr(names_col[54], 15, 18))
" SUS"
> substr(names_col[54], 15, 18) == " SUS"
[1] FALSE
```

```
> zed = " Calvin Ridley SUS"
> substr(zed, 15, 18) == " SUS"
[1] TRUE
```

Our hypothesis is that the   space in the first code block is something along the lines of an irregular space, due to the loading from excel. How can we fix this so we can match the substring in the first code block?

Comment: I am specifically trying to match on the 4 character sequence of space + SUS. Don't want to return TRUE for aSUS for example. Ahh i edited the other comment on accident, which recommended to use `trimws()`

Comment: You can use `charToRaw` to see the hex codes for each character.  A standard space is 20; others will vary depending on the encoding.

Comment: Can you [edit] in the output of `stringi::stri_escape_unicode(names_col[54])`?

Comment: `stringi::stri_escape_unicode(names_col[54])` returns `"\\u00a0Calvin Ridley\\u00a0SUS"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your string contains a "non-breaking space".

You can match using the unicode escape string:

```
target <- "\u00a0Calvin Ridley\u00a0SUS"
grepl("\u00a0SUS",target)
[1] TRUE
```

As user2554330 [mentions in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73281291/in-r-how-to-match-string-that-has-irregular-space/73281394#comment129418195_73281291), you can also use the raw hex codes, but it's more convoluted:

```
grepl(paste0(rawToChar(as.raw(c(0xc2, 0xa0))),"SUS"),target)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: is it possible to replace `\\u00a0` with ` ` across the entire dataframe? `names_col = gsub('\\u00a0', ' ', names_col)` does not work.

Comment: I think `mutate(DF,across(everything(),~str_replace_all(.x,"\u00a0"," ")))` should do it. It won't get the column names though. Use `rename_with`.